# svg SMIL animation transform origin question

Tags: svg, translate, smil, animatetransform

I cannot figure out where to put the transform origin and with what values at the second path (#tran) to resemble the first path (#drop). I want them both to move the same way. The path #tran is the one that I need to behave like the smooth d-animated #drop. Here is the code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
<path id="drop">
  <animate attributeName="d" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="M 50 0 Q 48 4 50 4 Q 52 4 50 0 Z; M 50 10 Q 48 6 50 6 Q 52 6 50 10 Z; M 50 0 Q 48 4 50 4 Q 52 4 50 0 Z;" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
<path id="tran" d="M 50 0 Q 48 4 50 4 Q 52 4 50 0 Z"  transform="translate(4,0)"/>
  </defs> 
  <use href="#drop"/><!--this is correct-->
  <use href="#tran" ><!--this one to behave like the one above (#drop)-->
<animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  attributeType="XML"
  type="scale"
  values="1 1;1 -1; 1 1"
  dur="3s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" /><!--transform-origin here? what values-->
<animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  attributeType="XML"
  type="translate"
  values="0 0; 0 -10; 0 0"
  dur="3s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum"/><!--transform-origin here? what values-->
  </use>
</svg>
```

I tried putting origin-transform all over the place, including css madness - but i prefer non-css - seems transform-origin does not work inside the animate tags. Okay, in a few days I might figure out the values with keysplines or something but I want a neat solution with few calculations. I'm trying to build a whole animation with a mandala being built rotated and mirrored so I need clean logic with as little math as possible -no javascript-.